# How to fix 'forge start' hangs

Tags: forge

`forge start` hangs for hours without printing any success or error message.

I have no idea what happened behind the scene, steps to reproduce the issue:

```
npm install -g @arcblock/forge-cli
forge init
forge start
```

It should start a local forge chain node in some reasonable time.